# razor pages bulk insert

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I created simple model Boats , i want to create razor page view which accept bulk insert records to database.
my code is working fine but just for single record.
My model

```
    public class boats
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Boatno { get; set; }

        public int Req_no { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Req_no")]
        public requests requests { get; set; }
    }
```

C#

```
        [BindProperty]
        public boats boats { get; set; }

        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            
            _context.boats.Add(boats);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
```

razor page view

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
           
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="boats.Boatno" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="boats.Boatno" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="boats.Boatno" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="boats.Req_no" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="boats.Req_no" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Req_no"></select>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
         
        </form>
```

so i tried many solution like create list then call it but it is not working or i mad something wrong
please not my code above is working fine but just for single record.

Comment: You mean that you create a list and then add and insert into the database after data selection works, now you want to add multiple lists and then filter the data for bulk insert, is that so?

Comment: No, just i want to insert 5 records at once from razor view form in one submit click